# Running the dll file of the "Fanny worm" virus

Tags: windows, dll, reverse-engineering, malware, kaspersky

I'm studying virus testing at university. I was given the task to investigate the "Fanny Worm" virus from the "Equation Group". For testing, I found a file dll_installer.dll described in the article from kaspersky. (https://securelist.com/a-fanny-equation-i-am-your-father-stuxnet/68787/). I wanted to test it on Windows XP x64 SP2, but I can't figure out how to infect the system with a dll file. I tried to run it through rundll32 and through regsvr32, but nothing worked.

Before that, I tested on Win 10, everything was successfully launched through the regsvr32, the virus made some changes in the register, but could not fully spread, because the virus is not aimed at such a new system (at least in win10 the file is missing "msagent.dll").